# Split the queries or multiple joins for independent tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've looked for hours for this and I can't find the proper solution. I'll start by saying what I'm expecting as a result with fictional tables. After parsing the sql query, I want to return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "storeID": 1,
    "storeName": "best store ever",
    "products": [
      {
        "productID": 1,
        "productName": "Name1",
        "productPrice": 10.00
      },
      {
        "productID": 2,
        "productName": "Name2",
        "productPrice": 10.00
      },
      {
        "productID": 3,
        "productName": "Name3",
        "productPrice": 10.00
      },
      ...
    ],
    "employees": [
      {
        "employeeID": 1,
        "employeeName": "Name1",
        "employeeSalary": 40000.00
      },
      {
        "employeeID": 2,
        "employeeName": "Name1",
        "employeeSalary": 45000.00
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

My problem is with the join of the stores table with the products and employees tables. Right now I'm doing this:

```
SELECT
  s.storeID,
  s.storeName,
  p.productID,
  p.productName,
  p.productPrice,
  e.employeeID,
  e.employeeName,
  e.employeeSalary,
FROM stores AS s
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.fk_store_id = s.storeID
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.fk_store_id = s.storeID;
```

With this I get products x employees number of rows for each store which is a significant overhead. If I can get to products + employees number of rows that would be ok. But that seem to be the same as doing 2 separate queries... One for the stores joining the products and one for the stores joining the employees.

What would be the more appropriate solution for this?

Comment: This will have to be two separate queries. Since the number of products and employees can be different, I don't see a way to do this cleanly in one query. You might be able to do a UNION since the columns are the same. But that is also technically 2 queries. Let me know if you need to see an example of how to do this with UNION.

Comment: True that in the example I gave the columns are the same and that a Union would work but in the actual problem that I have the columns aren't the same. So UNION wouldn't work. And doesn't it make it impossible to differentiate between the 2 tables when you do a UNION?

Comment: You can add another column stating the type of data. The columns would be storeId, storeName, type (employee/product), id, name, price/salary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of join you are trying here is not appropriate case of LEFT join. When you make a join between 3 tables: A, B and C; table A and B joins first and then with the result of this join, table C will be join. So, if both table B and C has data connected to all the rows of table A, then the total number of row will be n(A) * n(B) * n(C).

For your desire output, you need to have two queries. Alternatively, you can make one query, and then use your front end scripting to convert the result to your desire output.

Comment: That's what I was expecting to see as an answer. I'm just glad that someone confirmed it for me.

Comment: Reputation below 15 so my upvote does not show for now

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant by using a UNION. There will be some manipulation required to look at the type column and figure out how to handle it in the next layer.

```
SELECT
  s.storeID,
  s.storeName,
  'Employee' AS type,
  e.employeeID AS id,
  e.employeeName AS name,
  e.employeeSalary AS cost
FROM stores AS s
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.fk_store_id = s.storeID
UNION
SELECT
  s.storeID,
  s.storeName,
  'Product' AS type,
  p.productID,
  p.productName,
  p.productPrice
FROM stores AS s
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.fk_store_id = s.storeID;
```

Single query using a join is not possible since there is no direct relation between product and employee so you will be joining with store and that will give you a product X employee join.